# Can't connect remote jetty ajp service

Tags: jetty, ajp

How can I allow public access to jetty-ajp service? I am able to connect locally  ajp://localhost:8009/ but not from a remote node using schema  ajp://192.168.2.1:8009/ . I achieved it with port forwarding but want to know if there is an another way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJP is not supported by Eclipse Jetty.

If you must use Apache Httpd as a front end of Eclipse Jetty, know that the Eclipse Jetty project recommends using the `mod_proxy` services of Apache Httpd.

See:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425244
- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/134

If you are running an older version of Jetty that had AJP support, know that all of those versions are now EOL (End of Life).

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

Comment: In my current project apache and jetty is communicating through ajp protocol.

Comment: Then you are running an ancient long since EOL (End of Life) declared version of Jetty. (as pointed out in the answer)